# Trouble with Autohotkey key combination

Tags: autohotkey

I have seen various references that say you can make key combinations by seperating the keys using the ampersand symbol `&`. When I implement this, somehow it doesn't work.

Why would this script:

```
Up::Volume_Up
Down::Volume_Down
```

work? and this one:

```
LCtrl & Up::Volume_Up
LCtrl & Down::Volume_Down
```

Not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you use the send command

```
LCtrl & Up:: Send {Volume_Up}
LCtrl & Down:: Send {Volume_Down}
```

or

```
<^Up:: Send {Volume_Up}
<^Down:: Send {Volume_Down}
```

"LCtrl & Up" isn't a key you can replace with another. It's a combination of two keys.